# JQUERY - Table TD text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the **td** value from below HTML using JQUERY after clicking on **Edit** link
and separate it into 3 separate variables like below

```
company=Microsoft Technologies
Period = 2011/3 - Current
designation = Software Engineer



<table summary="My Company" id="mylistbl">  
    <thead> 
        <tr>    
            <th scope="col">Company</th> 
            <th scope="col">Action</th> 
        </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
        <tr object_type="999920113" object_id="872733">
            <td width="290">Microsoft Technologies<br><span style="font-size:11px; color:#555;">Period : 2011/3 - Current <br>Designation : Software Engineer</span>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#" title="Delete">Delete</a>/<a href="#" title="Edit">Edit</a>
            </td>  
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



 $('body').on('click','a[title="Edit"]',
        function(){
            parObj=$(this).parent().parent(); 
            alert(parObj.children()[0].html);
            return false;
        });
```

I think somewhere in **parObj.children()[0].html** I am doing wrong to get the desired text

Here is JSFiddle for it

http://jsfiddle.net/FjXLp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[title="Edit"]', function () {
    parObj = $(this).closest('tr');
    alert(parObj.children('td:eq(0)').html());

    // Get the first part like
    var main = parObj.children('td:eq(0)').html().split('<br>');
    var company = $.trim(main[0]);
    console.log(company);  // Microsoft Technologies

    // Second part like
    var Period  = $.trim(main[1].replace('<span style="font-size:11px; color:#555;">',''));
    console.log(Period);  // Period : 2011/3 - Current

    // Third part like
    var designation  = $.trim(main[2].replace('</span>',''));
    console.log(designation);   // Designation : Software Engineer
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) which returns a jquery object:

http://jsfiddle.net/FjXLp/1/

```
alert(parObj.children().eq(0).html());
```

Comment: Thank You roasted for giving me info on eq method , +1 for it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
parObj.children().eq(0).html()
```

When you used `parObj.children()[0]` that gave you a reference to the actual DOM element that is the first child (or `undefined` if there were no children) and DOM elements don't have an `html` property. They do have an `innerHTML` property, but the usual jQuery way would be to use `.eq(0)` to get the first child wrapped in a jQuery object and then use the jQuery `.html()` method.

Comment: `parObj.children(0).html()` this also works but I am not sure why some one has downvoted this solution once.

Comment: @Mr_Green - I think you'll find that that works only by accident - `.children(0)` doesn't actually return the first child, it returns all of them, but `.html()` returns the contents of the only first element in the set. (http://jsfiddle.net/cy4Ha/)

Comment: @Mr_Green .children( [selector ] ) But now im thinking it will be a nice feature if we could pass an index as parameter to children() method

Comment: yeah that would be nice.. thanks for the explanation guys. :)

Comment: Thank You nnnnnn for giving me info on eq method , +1 for it

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible, I'd recommend you to place each data inside a span tag. Then you can handle it simply as follows:

```html
<td width="290">
    <span>Microsoft Technologies</span><br/>
    <span style="font-size:11px; color:#555;">Period : 2011/3 - Current</span><br/>
    <span>Designation : Software Engineer</span>
</td>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', 'a[title="Edit"]', function() {
        var spans = $(this).parents('tr').children('td:first').children('span');
        var company = spans[0].innerHTML;
        var period = spans[1].innerHTML.split(':')[1];
        var designation = spans[2].innerHTML.split(':')[1];
        alert(company + ';' + period + ';' + designation);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FjXLp/2/

Comment: Thank You Stano for this solution . As you said I will talk to the team and ask them to put in separate span tags .Palash Mondal provided the solution first , so I gave +1 for you and did set his answer as correct one . Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Bujji, you're absolutely right that Palash's solution is good. And I am glad if this one can be also helpful. Greetings